# ¿Como obtener la fecha en un entry?

Tags: python

soy nuevo incursionando tanto en Tkinter y lo que llevo lo he conseguido por medio de tutoriales, pero llevo semanas tratanto de encontrar una solución pero no lo encuentro, espero y me puedan ayudar, se los agradecería bastante.
Tengo mi codigo el cual quiero que en un entry me bote la fecha que selecciono el cual es asi:

```
    root = Tk()
    root.title('CALENDARIO')
    root.geometry("250x220")
    root.iconbitmap("LOGO.ico")

    year = datetime.date.today().year
    month = datetime.date.today().month
    day = datetime.date.today().day

    cal = Calendar(root, year=year, month=month, day=day)
    cal.pack()

    def grab_date():
        self.fechaing_bus.config(text=cal.get_date())


    my_button = Button(root, text="SELECCIONAR", command=grab_date, bg="green2")
    my_button.pack(pady=5)
    

    self.fechaing_bus=tk.StringVar()
    self.fechaing_buscar=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1,width="11",font=("cambria",11),textvariable=self.fechaing_bus)
    self.fechaing_buscar.grid(column=1,row=12,sticky="w")
```

El error que me aparece es este:

```
self.fechaing_bus.config(text=cal.get_date())
```

AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'config'

Lo he tratato de cambiar de varias formas, pero no tengo exito y me gustaria permanecerlo a Entry y no cambiarlo a un Label.
Agradezco su tiempo y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO ES Óscar!
Tu problema se debe a que la forma que usas para establecer el contenido del entry no es la correcta.
Para modificar el contenido de un entry, tienes que modificar el valor del `StringVar` asociado a él (asocias el StringVar al entry con el argumento `textvariable` cuando lo creas).
Para acceder al valor de un `StringVar` tienes que usar el método `.get` y para cambiarlo, usar el `.set`.
Aquí abajo te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

v=Tk()

s=StringVar()
s.set("establesco un valor al StringVar")

print(s.get())
```

Por lo tanto, el código de tu función debería de quedar así:

```
def grab_date():
    self.fechaing_bus.set(cal.get_date())
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier duda que tengas dime.

Comment: Increíble, para ti es sencillo pero para mi es algo nuevo, agradezco tu respuesta y el tiempo tomado por haberme explicado. No cabe duda que necesito mas conocimiento profesional.
Saludos y nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer. Estoy seguro de que algún día te será sencillo también. Suerte! c: